# How to replace redux reducers and thunks with React Hooks API

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have been handed a project and been told to use `React Hooks` instead of `Redux` as much as possible. Is it possible to replace the reducers and thunks below with React Hooks? Is it worth it to replace?

Reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {createActions, createReducer, Types as ReduxSauceTypes} from 'reduxsauce'
import { reducer as ProfileReducer } from '@Reducers/Profile'

const appReducer = combineReducers({
    profile: ProfileReducer,
    // other reducers
})

const { Types, Creators: Actions } = createActions({
    resetApp: []
})

const rootReducer = createReducer([], {
    [Types.RESET_APP]: (state, action) => {
        return appReducer(undefined, action)
        //Passing undefined as state will make all the reducers using their initial states.
    },
    [ReduxSauceTypes.DEFAULT]: (state, action) => {
        return appReducer(state, action)
    }
})

const resetReduxStore = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(Actions.resetApp())
    }
}

export { rootReducer, resetReduxStore }
```

Reducers/Profile/index.js

```
import { createActions, createReducer } from 'reduxsauce';
export { default as thunks } from './thunks.js';

/* ------------- Initial State ------------- */
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
    user: {},
};

/* ------------- Types and Action Creators ------------- */
export const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
    setUser        : ['user'],
});

/* ------------- Hookup Reducers To Types ------------- */
export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
    [Types.SET_USER]: (state, { user }) => {
        return {
            ...state,
            user
        };
    },
});

export default Creators;
```

Comment: Is there more in your `'./thunks.js'` file?  I'm just seeing one thunk here.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it worth it?" is a matter of opinion, but I'll give mine.

#### Re: useReducer

React now has a [`useReducer` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) that allows you to update a state by dispatching actions.  You can use the same reducers that you have already.  By default, `useReducer` only manages the state for the component that it's in.  It doesn't come with a context provider.  You could create your own context but at that point you are re-creating Redux.

My opinion: Use the React `useReducer` hook if you have state that it localized to one part of your app.  Keep the reducer in some component and pass down callbacks and values via props.  If you have state that is global in nature then use Redux.

#### Re: useState

You asked if you can replace your reducers.  As I said, the `useReducer` hook would use the same sort of reducer so you wouldn't be replacing it.  Perhaps the question you need to be asking is *do I need a reducer-like system to update this state?*

My Opinion: The code that you've posted here is extremely simple and it would be a good candidate for a basic `useState` hook.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState();
```

You could combine this with a context provider and a `useContext` hook to have a global profile state.  If you start having multiple contexts for multiple states -- that's when you want to use Redux instead.

```
const UserContext = React.createContext([
  undefined, // user
  () => {} // setUser
]);

// takes no `value` because the state is internal
export const UserProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState<MaybeUser>();

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[user, setUser]}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useUser = () => useContext(UserContext);
```

Usage in some component:

```
const Test = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useUser();
  ...
}
```

#### Re: Thunks

Thunks are function of `dispatch` so they can easily be rewritten with the `useDispatch` hook, if using Redux.  You can use the `useSelector` hook instead of the `getState()` argument of a thunk.

There are lots of ways to replace thunks using hooks.  But the only thunk that you have here is your `resetReduxStore` which really doesn't need to be a thunk.